# Schauder basis that is not Hilbert basis

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

- Given an infinite dimensional **Banach** space $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ over the field $\Bbb K=\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$, a countable ordered set $B:=\{b_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}⊂V$ is called ***Schauder basis***, if every $v\in V$ can be uniquely decomposed as:
  $$ v=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}c_nb_n \tag1$$
  for a set (generally infinite) of numbers $c_n\in\mathbb K$ depending on $v$, where the convergence of the sum is referred both to the Banach space topology and to the order used in labelling $B$. Identity $(1)$ is then taken to be equivalent to:
  $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left\|v−\sum_{n=1}^mc_nb_n\right\|=0$$
- Given an infinite dimensional **Hilbert** space $(V,\langle\cdot | \cdot\rangle)$ over the field $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$, a set $B⊂V$ is called ***Hilbert basis***, or *complete orthonormal system*, if the following conditions are true:

  1. $⟨z|z⟩=1$ and $⟨z|z′⟩=0$ if $z,z'∈B$ and $z≠z'$, i.e. $B$ is an orthonormal system;
  2. if $x \in V$ and $⟨x|z⟩=0$ for all $z\in B$ then $x=0$ (i.e. $B$ is maximal with respect to the orthogonality requirment).

If $(V,\langle\cdot | \cdot\rangle)$ is *separable*, i.e. it contains a dense countable subset, then every Hilbert basis is also a Schauder basis with respect to the norm induced by the Hilbert scalar product. However, the converse is not generally true. *Are there any explicit examples of Schauder bases of infinite-dimensional, separable Hilbert spaces that are not Hilbert bases?*

Comment: It is very simple. Consider the basis $(1,1), (1,0)$ of $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with the usual scalar product $(x, y)\cdot( x', y')=xx'+yy'$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro My question is in the context of infinite dimensional vector spaces. I will specify this in an edit

Comment: A trivial example:  if $\{b_n\}$ is a Hilbert basis, replace $b_1$ by $2b_1$.  No longer orthonormal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to go to the infinite dimensional case. Consider the immediate $\mathbb R^2$ example $v_1=(1,1), v_2=(1,0)$. Once you have that, you trivially construct an infinite-dimensional example in $\ell^2$ by setting 
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
b_1 & =& (v_1, 0,0,0\ldots) \\ 
b_2 &=& (v_2, 0 ,0 ,0\ldots)\\ 
b_3 &=& (0,0,1,0,0\ldots)\\ 
b_4 &=& (0,0,0,1,0\ldots)\\
&\vdots&\\ 
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't seeing the immediate generalization to $\ell^2$ of what you said in the comments.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helped.

Comment: Heyy, really like your answer, if you could help with an exercise, would really appreciate it :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096022/normed-vector-space-schauder-basis-exercise